# classify a single text document in naive bayes in weka

Tags: java, weka, arff

I am unsure on how am i supposed to create a unlabelled arff text document in weka. I currently am trying to read an unlabelled txt document from disk to classify based on the model i have built. However, to convert a text document to arff, I am currently using

`java weka.core.converters.TextDirectoryLoader` which effectively assigns a class label to the document.

Hence, the arff would be labelled instead. My text files will be of arbitrary length.

I have checked the wikispaces for examples but it seems it just loads an unlabelled arff without explaining how do i go about creating it.

Example

### Test.txt

I have a long long long string

---

How do i convert this to arff format for use in this code ***unlabeled.arff***

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.BufferedWriter;
 import java.io.FileReader;
 import java.io.FileWriter;
 import weka.core.Instances;
 ...
 // load unlabeled data
 Instances unlabeled = new Instances(
                         new BufferedReader(
                           new FileReader("/some/where/unlabeled.arff")));

 // set class attribute
 unlabeled.setClassIndex(unlabeled.numAttributes() - 1);

 // create copy
 Instances labeled = new Instances(unlabeled);

 // label instances
 for (int i = 0; i < unlabeled.numInstances(); i++) {
   double clsLabel = tree.classifyInstance(unlabeled.instance(i));
   labeled.instance(i).setClassValue(clsLabel);
 }
 // save labeled data
 BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                           new FileWriter("/some/where/labeled.arff"));
 writer.write(labeled.toString());
 writer.newLine();
 writer.flush();
 writer.close();
```

This code is obtained from the weka wiki spaces example

Comment: I'm sorry, but what is the question here?  Is the question how do you create an arff from your text document?  An arff is essentially a csv file with a descriptive header up top and the data being proceded by @ DATA.  You can define each attribute in the header using @ ATTRIBUTE. It should be created in column order

Comment: @Razs Apps i have edited my question

Comment: what about using Remove filter just to remove class attribute, and then save as arff?...

Comment: @makak what i am trying to do is classify a new document hence, i don't think that is feasible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a directory with the directory name as ? and placing the test document into the folder and converted to arff using TextDirectoryLoader. It worked for me but i doubt it is the best solution.